# Unset specific billing state (county) when country is GB/UK on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm looking for a way to remove specific billing_state fields.
For UK/ GB or switzerland for example.

I tried this but this isn't working:

```
function mp_change_locale_field_defaults($countries) {
    $countries['GB']['state']['hidden'] = true;
    return $countries;
}
```

The problem is, I cannot remove the billing state once and for all because it is relevant for other countries. 
So I cannot use

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields','simple_remove_billing_fields');
    function simple_remove_billing_fields( $fields = array() ) {
    unset($fields['billing_state']);
    return $fields;
}
```

I looked into class-wc-countries.php as well but I also did not find the line where I can manually edit this.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: can I set up a rule like this? if #billing_country option value=UK (or switzerland for example) then unset #billing_state or with css: display: none

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses jQuery to hide the state/county field when UK is selected.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'xs_conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field', 9999 );


function xs_conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field() {
   wc_enqueue_js( "
      jQuery('#billing_country').change(function() {
         if (jQuery('#billing_country :selected').text() === 'United Kingdom (UK)') {
            jQuery('#billing_state_field').hide();
         } else {
            jQuery('#billing_state_field').show();
         }
      }).change();
   ");
}
```